# How to use tables from database in apex 19.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I've installed Oracle APEX 19.2, on database 12.2. And I don't know how to use tables which exist in database. For instance, I have table 'test' in database and I can't use this table in app builder. I searched in google, but I couldn't find appropriate answer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a workspace, you have to "pair" database users (schemas) with your workspace. It is done in administrative part of Apex (you have to log in as `ADMIN`).

Once you do that, you'll be able to see tables owned by that user.